# Is a UITableView less than full width against HIG?

Tags: ios, uitableview, app-store

The Human Interface Guidelines for a `UITableView` state: "plain tables display rows that extend from side edge to side edge of the screen."  Does this mean that a `UITableView` that is less than full-screen width would be rejected from the App Store?

[iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1/iOS%20UI%20Element%20Usage%20Guidelines)

Comment: Absolutely not!  Far be it from apple to discourage you from modifying the standard controls (just don't try to reach outside your sandbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I dont think your app will be rejected just because your tableView is not full screen. Some of the things in HIG are guidelines not hard & fast rules. For example in apple settings you can see this -

[image]

This is `tableView` (the one on right) & its not full screen. There you go...